# Use link_to to pass params to a form hidden_field in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `has_many through:` relationship in my app where a `person` `has_many` `occasions` through `gifts` and visa versa.  I have a chart with the `person` on the y axis and the `occasion` on the x axis, like this:

[image]

The code is like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
            <th></th>
        <% @occasions.each do |occasion| %>
            <th style="padding: 0 5px 0 5px"><p><%= occasion.name %></p></th>
        <% end %>
    </tr>
    <% @people.each do |person| %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#edit-recipient-popup" class="open-popup-link">
                    <p><strong><%= person.name %></strong></p>
                </a>
            </td>
            <% @occasions.each do |occasion| %>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <% gifts = Gift.where(person_id: person.id, occasion_id: occasion.id) %>
                    <% if gifts != [] %>
                        <% gifts.each do |gift| %>
                            <div class="text-left">
                                <% if gift.purchased %>
                                    <i class="icon ion-android-checkbox-outline green"></i>
                                <% else %>
                                    <i class="icon ion-android-checkbox-outline-blank green"></i>
                                <% end %>
                                <%= link_to gift.name, gift_path(gift.id), person_id: person.id, occasion_id: occasion.id %>
                            </div>
                        <% end %>
                    <% else %>
                        <h1>
                            <%= link_to new_gift_path do %>
                                <i class="icon ion-ios-plus-empty green"></i>
                            <% end %> <!-- link -->
                        </h1>
                    <% end %> <!-- if/else end -->
                </td>
            <% end %> <!-- occasions each -->
        </tr>
    <% end %> <!-- people each -->
</table>
```

I somehow need to change the link for a new gift:

```
<%= link_to gift.name, gift_path(gift.id) %>
```

To somehow pass the params for which `person` and `occasion` that plus sign is indicating.  The following doesn't work, but I need something like this:

```
<%= link_to gift.name, gift_path(gift.id), person_id: person.id, occasion_id: occasion.id %>
```

I've checked a bunch of other SO posts, but can't find one that does what I'm looking for.

Ideally I would be able to include params in the `link_to` so that when the form for `gift#new` came up, I could include hidden fields with the associated values, like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@gift) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :price %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
    <%= f.input :link %>
    <%= f.input :purchased %>
    <%= f.association :user %>
    <%= f.text_field :occasion_id, value: @occasion %>
    <%= f.text_field :person_id, value: @person %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I know something like this is possible in Rails, but I can't figure out the syntax.

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

I tried the method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773695/rails-passing-parameters-in-link-to) with a link like this:

```
<%= link_to new_gift_path(:gift => { person_id: person.id, occasion_id: occasion.id }) do %>
```

And the `gifts#new` controller method like this:

```
def new
  @gift = Gift.new(params[:gift])
end
```

But this approach gave me an error saying `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` on the controller definition for `@gift`.

Comment: @Pavan, I had actually tried that question's approach, but I got an error.  I edited the OP as to what happened.

Comment: Check the other answer and try it as specified.

Comment: @Pavan, I thought I did?

Comment: Nope. You didn't. Try `<%= link_to new_gift_path(person_id: person.id, occasion_id: occasion.id) do %>` and access those with `params[:person_id]` and `params[:occasion_id]` in the controller method

Comment: I think I'm doing the `gifts#new` wrong (`@gift = Gift.new(params[:person_id], params[:occasion_id])`) because I'm getting `When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
`?

Comment: Don't go by the accepted answer, ignore it completely. Just define instance variables to store `params[:person_id]` and `params[:occasion_id]` and access those in the form

Comment: @Pavan, I can see it's passing them because my link is `http://localhost:3000/gifts/new?occasion_id=1&person_id=2`, but when I create the new `gift` it still isn't saving them....