# Syntax error when adding params to link_to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get an "syntax error, unexpected `end', expecting end-of-input" when trying to add params to link_to

**html**

```
<%= link_to  "showdeals"(id: "test"), target: :_blank  do %>
                <img src="/assets/images/1.png">
<% end%>
```

the following code without params works fine

```
<%= link_to  "showdeals", target: :_blank  do %>
                <img src="/assets/images/1.png">
<% end%>
```

[EDIT]
The answer below by Max worked and the explanation was super helpful in my understanding. I created a named path for my route using as: :showdeals. Then the following code

```
<%= link_to showdeals_path(id: "test"), target: :_blank  do %>
                <img src="/assets/images/1.png">
              <% end%>
```

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. You can add params to the text portion of the link_to. What model are you trying to make a link_to for? Also "test" is not an ID unless your Database actually as an ID column with text as the values.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773695/rails-passing-parameters-in-link-to

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails - passing parameters in link\_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773695/rails-passing-parameters-in-link-to)

Comment: @Beartech stranger things have happened on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `link_to` or even Rails.

In Ruby its syntactically invalid to follow a literal (string, array, hash) with `(`.

```
irb(main):001:0> "foo"(bar: 2)
/home/max/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/irb-1.4.2/lib/irb/workspace.rb:119:in `eval': (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
"foo"(bar: 2)
 ^
```

Perhaps you meant to call a path helper:

```
<%= link_to  "showdeals", deal_path(id: "test"), target: :_blank  do %>
  <img src="/assets/images/1.png">
<% end %>
```

Or pass a hash to the polymorphic routes helpers:

```
<%= link_to  "showdeals", { action: :show, id: "test" }, target: :_blank  do %>
  <img src="/assets/images/1.png">
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter should be the URL you would like to link. Try using the link

```
<%= link_to "showdeals", "my/link/goes/here", target: :_blank  do %>
   <img src="/assets/images/1.png">
<% end%>
```

Or ideally, you would have a resourceful link helper:

```
<%= link_to "showdeals", model_name_path(id: 1), target: :_blank  do %>
   <img src="/assets/images/1.png">
<% end%>
```