# Problems with passing parameters using link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've been trying to implement this answer into my app ([Rails - passing parameters in link_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773695/rails-passing-parameters-in-link-to)) As it addresses my problem directly but i can't get it to work. Can someone look at my code and tell my what i'm doing wrong. Here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admins, path: 'admins'
  devise_for :employees, path: 'employees'
  namespace :employees do
    resources :kudos
    resources :rewards, only: [:index, :show], shallow: true do
      resources :orders, only: [:create, :new]
    end
  end
  namespace :admins do
    resources :kudos, only: [:index, :destroy]
    resources :employees, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    resources :company_values
    resources :rewards
  end
  get '/admin' => "admins/pages#dashboard", :as => :admin_root
  root 'employees/kudos#index'
end
```

Here is my orders controller

```
module Employees
  module Rewards
    class OrdersController < EmployeesController
      def new
        @order= Order.new
       if params[:reward_id]
            @order.reward_id = params[:reward_id]
        end
      end
      def create
        @order = Order.new(order_params)
        @order.employee = current_employee
        @order.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Reward was successfully bought'
        redirect_to rewards_path
      end

        private

      def order_params
        params.require(:order).permit(:employee_id, :reward_id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and my rewards controller

```
class RewardsController < EmployeesController
    def index
     @rewards = Reward.all 
    end

    def show
      render :show, locals: { reward: Reward.find(params[:id]) }
    end

    private

    def reward_params
      params.require(:reward).permit(:title, :description, :price)
    end
  end
```

And last but not least my rewards index view:

```
<h1>Rewards listing page</h1>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Show Reward</th>
      <th>Buy Reward</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @rewards.each do |reward| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= reward.title %></td>
          <td><%= reward.price %></td>
        <td><%=button_to 'Show',  employees_reward_path(reward), method: :get %></td>
        <td><%=link_to 'Buy',  new_employees_reward_order_path(:order=>{:reward_id => reward.id}) %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Right now i'm getting the following error

```
Showing /home/valar/Dokumenty/ERP_v1/app/views/employees/rewards/index.html.erb where line #18 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"employees/orders", :order=>{:reward_id=>6}}, missing required keys: [:reward_id]
Did you mean?  new_employees_reward_order_url
```

And if I pass an instance variable like this (like the answer suggested):

```
link_to 'Buy',  new_employees_reward_order_path(:order=>{:reward_id => @reward.id})
```

i get the `` undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass `` error
Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT I enclose a pic of my structure[image: structure]

Comment: ```ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Employees::Rewards#index
Showing /home/valar/Dokumenty/ERP_v1/app/views/employees/rewards/index.html.erb where line #18 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"employees/orders", :reward_id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:reward_id]
``` is what I'm getting after implementing your advice @dbugger

Comment: should be `link_to 'Buy',  new_employees_reward_order_path(reward)` because you are looping through rewards

Comment: @dbugger now i get ```Routing Error
uninitialized constant Employees::OrdersController candidate = constant.const_get(name) ^^^^^^^^^^ Did you mean? Employees::RewardsController raise MissingController.new(error.message, error.name) ^^^^^
``` i think i have a nesting problem somewhere...but i checked my catalogue structure and it's ok.

Comment: that's pretty clear that your routing is not in agreement with your controller class structure. And that's a different question.

Comment: @dbugger could you at least please tell me if I could nest modules as shown in orders_controller. and i also enclose a pic of my catalogue structure if you could take a quick look at it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with this. Lets start with the routes - if you want to route to the controller `Employees::Rewards::OrdersController` you need to configure it explicitly:

```
resources :orders, only: [:create, :new], module: :rewards
```

Nesting resources doesn't imply module nesting. And your controller should look like this:

```
class Reward < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders
end
```

```
module Employees
  module Rewards
    class OrdersController < EmployeesController
      before_action :set_reward

      # GET /employees/rewards/1/orders/new
      def new
        @order = @reward.orders.new
      end

      # POST /employees/rewards/1/orders 
      def create
        @order = @reward.orders.new(employee: current_employee)
        # Do not just assume that the record will always be saved 
        if @order.save
          flash[:notice] = 'Reward was successfully bought'
          redirect_to rewards_path
        else
          render :new
        end
      end

      private

      def set_reward
        # this should cause a 404 - Not Found Response if the reward cannot be found
        @reward = Reward.find(params[:reward_id])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Note that you should be getting the parent resource id from the URL and the current user from the session. So you don't actually need strong parameters.

And when creating a nested resource make sure you actually find the parent resource first so that an error is raised early and rescued with 404 - Not Found response if an invalid parent id is used. Otherwise you'll either end up with NoMethodErrors, foreign key violations or a lack of referential integrity.

You can then link to the new action either by calling the path helper with an instance of reward:

```
<%= link_to 'Buy', new_employees_reward_order_path(reward) %>
```

But since you don't seem to be actually taking any user input you could just create a button that goes straight to the create action:

```
<%= button_to 'Buy', employees_reward_orders_path(reward), method: :post %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the time you took in crafting your answer. What if this line ``` @reward = Reward.find(params[:reward_id])``` can't find the reward and gives me the```ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Employees::Rewards::OrdersController#create
Couldn't find Reward without an ID``` error ?

Comment: Rails rescues `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` by sending a 404 response and rendering an error page which is the correct response if you try to add a nested resource to something that doesn't exist.

Comment: But the reward exists...

Comment: Ah sorry. What `Couldn't find Reward without an ID` means is that `params[:reward_id]` is actually nil. Why this is happening is something that you'll have figure out with some basic debugging. Check the value of `reward` in the view where you're creating the link, the rendered html and check the parameters from the rails log.

Comment: As a debugging step you can explicitly pass the parameter instead ie. `new_employees_reward_order_path(reward_id: reward.id)` but this should not actually be needed.

Comment: I'm sorry max but it's all new to me. When you say check the parameters from the rails log you mean the development.log file? If yes then it says ```Completed 404 Not Found``` and upon inspecting the Buy element in the html view it doesn't have any value,

Comment: Oh and passing explicitly the params (reward_id: reward.id) gives me the ```undefined method `orders' for #<Reward id: 1, title:...``` error in line```def create
        @order = @reward.orders.new(employee: current_employee)
        if @order.save```

Comment: Yeah you need to define a `has_many :orders` assocation in your Reward model.

Comment: you were right max i thought that i made that association but it appeared i made a mistke in it. So finaly this syntax works  ``` <td><%=button_to 'Buy',  employees_orders_path(reward_id: reward.id), method: :post%></td>```